# signalR undefined but signalr.js is loaded in the debugger

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to use SignalR for ASP.NET Core 2.0, but when I try to implement the SignalR client in my View, I get the error that the variable "signalR" is undefined despite auto-completion working fine in my editor, Here is the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _transport = signalR.TransportType.WebSockets; //HERE
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection(`http://${document.location.host}/chat`, {transport: _transport});

var messageInput = document.getElementById('message');
var name = '@User.Identity.Name';
var button = document.getElementById('sendMessage');

connection.on('broadcastMessage', (name, message) => {
    var text = document.createElement('p');
    text.innerHTML = '<strong>' + name + '</strong>' + "&nbsp;:&nbsp;" + message;

    document.getElementById('messageArea').appendChild(text);
});

button.addEventListener("click", event => {    
    connection.invoke('send', name, messageInput.value);
    messageInput.value = '';
    messageInput.focus();
});

connection.start();
```

I have added the signalr.js in my _Layout.cshtml
[image: Environment include in _Layout.cshtml]

Here is the tree structure of my wwwroot where I've added the .js files for signalr :

[image: Tree structure in wwwroot]

And finally, here is the debugger structure in Firefox where I can see that the signalr.js has been loaded, and so are jQuery and bootstrap..

[image: signalr correctly loaded..?]

So why is "signalR" undefined? What am I missing? Is it because I've added the signalr javascript files manually in my project? (Probably...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script is executed before the signalr.js is loaded. Try to use an event to execute your code. IF we do this on document load then we'll be sure that it's defined.

```
$(document).load(function(){
   // your code here
});
```

Comment: Now I feel dumb. Thank you.

Although, wouldn't it be $(document).ready instead of $(document).load?

Comment: ready() is when the dom is loaded, the load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded, so i think load is better in this case.